# What are the Guidewire Claim Migration Tools available?

Tags: guidewire

Can you recommend the claim migration tools available to migrate claims into version 9 ?

I think the Claim Migration Tool (CMT) supports only the Version 10 and above ( Cloud ). Not sure which is suitable for Version 9 ?

Comment: There is a "Data Extractor for InsuranceSuite 9.0.4" in the Guidewire Marketplace that has this description "This tool is intended to assist in data migration from legacy systems into the Guidewire target system. It provides both Full Extraction for all products Staging Data Extraction for BillingCenter, ClaimCenter, and ContactManage." What is your specific problem? Are you trying to migrate claims from a Legacy System into ClaimCenter 9? More details would help me with providing a better answer.

Comment: I want to find the better tool / options to migrate legacy claims into Claim Center 9. I saw the Data Extractor at Market Place but couldnt find any doc as it has code files in zip.  I have used PMT ( Policy migration Tool ) to migrate legacy policies similarly there is CMT which helps to migrate claims to GW CC but it supports only V10 and above . So want to check with broader group of people if my understanding is correct and hear thoughts of other available options for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the CMT tooling - which as you've already documented is only supported on v10 and Cloud releases - the only migration mechanism for ClaimCenter is to use the ootb staging table capabilities.

Many customers have used generic ETL tooling to extract and prepare claim data for staging table loading.  In addition the Data Extractor content available in Marketplace can support these use cases.

In general, the extract and preparation tasks for claim migration have been considered to be project work and unique to each customer.